# How to obtain distinct values in knockout js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, distinct-values

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate array values and get distinct values in `knockout js`.

My code is as follows

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:53489/api/datacollect/GetPatientUDData',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; data.length; i++) {
            vModel.UDTableDesc.push(data[i]);
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error in Operation');
    }
});

function viewModel() {
    var viewModel = this;
    viewModel.UDTableDesc = ko.observableArray();
    return viewModel;
}

var vModel = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vModel, document.getElementById("MainTree"));
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What exactly would make two values in the `UDTableDesc` array a duplicate?

Answer (score -1):

Try checking for existence before you `push` an entry onto the array:

```
for (var i = 0; data.length; i++) {
  if (vModel.uDTableDesc.indexOf(data[i]) === -1) {
    vModel.UDTableDesc.push(data[i]);
  }
}
```